# Use split to remove parts of a string that are surrounded by curly double quotes

Tags: c#, split

I use the following as a parameter to the `split` function in C#:

```
    private char[] delimiterComment = { '(', '{', '[', '\u201C' };
    private char[] delimiterEndComment = { ')', '}', ']', '\u201D' };
```

It works on all the "brackets" but not the "curly double quotes". I don't understand why. Is it a bug in `split`, or a feature of the curly quote characters?

I have as an input string something like:
“this is a pre comment” then some vital info [there might be an embedded comment] and then some more vital info (then there is a post comment)

I wish to strip off the comments, but capture them in a structure, leaving a clean info string. It all worked beautifully with brackets, till I tried to add curly double quotes as additional delimiters...
(I am aware that embedded comments are being gathered as post comments deliberately)
The code I have written is as follows:

```
class CommentSplit
{
    public bool split = false;
    public bool error = false;
    public string original = "";
    public string remainder = "";
    public string preComment = "";
    public string postComment = "";

    public CommentSplit(string inString, char[] startComment, char[] endComment, string[] ignoreStrings, string[] addStrings, bool usePre) // creator
    {
        if (inString == null)
            return;
        original = inString;
        string[] starts = inString.Split(startComment);
        if (starts.Length == 1)
        {
            remainder = inString;
            return;
        }
        if (starts[0] != "")
            remainder += starts[0].TrimEnd();
        for (int i = 1; i < starts.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] ends = starts[i].Split(endComment);
            if (ends.Length != 2) // more than one end comment for a start comment - BUT what about one start and one end comment
            {
                error = true;
                return;
            }
            if (addStrings == null)
            {
                if (ignoreStrings == null)
                {
                    if ((remainder == "") && usePre)
                        preComment += ends[0];
                    else
                        postComment += ends[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    bool ignore = false;
                    for (int z = 0; z < ignoreStrings.Length; z++)
                    {
                        if (ends[0].ToLower() == ignoreStrings[z])
                            ignore = true;
                    }
                    if (!ignore) // was a comment but we might want to ignore it
                    {
                        if ((remainder == "") && usePre)
                        {
                            if (preComment != "")
                                preComment += " ";
                            preComment += ends[0];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (postComment != "")
                                postComment += " ";
                            postComment += ends[0];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                bool add = false;
                for (int z = 0; z < addStrings.Length; z++)
                {
                    if (ends[0].ToLower() == addStrings[z])
                        add = true;
                }
                if (add) // was a comment but want it in the remainder
                {
                    if (remainder != "")
                        remainder += " ";
                    remainder += ends[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    if (ignoreStrings == null)
                    {
                        if ((remainder == "") && usePre)
                            preComment += ends[0];
                        else
                            postComment += ends[0];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bool ignore = false;
                        for (int z = 0; z < ignoreStrings.Length; z++)
                        {
                            if (ends[0].ToLower() == ignoreStrings[z])
                                ignore = true;
                        }
                        if (!ignore) // was a comment but we might want to ignore it
                        {
                            if ((remainder == "") && usePre)
                            {
                                if (preComment != "")
                                    preComment += " ";
                                preComment += ends[0];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (postComment != "")
                                    postComment += " ";
                                postComment += ends[0];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            if (remainder != "")
                remainder += " ";
            remainder += ends[1].Trim();
        }
        split = true;
    } // CommentSplit
}
```

I should note that I am a retired C programmer dabbling in C#, so my style may not be OOP efficient. I did originally include straight (non curly) double quotes, but they are not important, and indeed stuff things up as there is not an pre and post delimiter version of them.

Comment: Can you give a sample input and expected output?

Comment: provide more code actually where you doing split.

Comment: Could you provide *some examples* of the desired behavior? E.g. what is the expected outcome for `"(123) [{456}] \"\" (7\"89)"`, `"[123)"`, `"([123)]"`?

Comment: @Andrew Truckle I approved your edit. I'd like to point out that, when editing, you should also [remove greetings and thanks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/168333), and remove tags from titles.

Comment: I have added code and more info. Curly quotes are the issue in reality

Answer (score 0):

Its something else in your code as this small verifiable example works fine:

```
char[] delimiterComment = { '(', '{', '[', '\u201C', '\u201D', '"', '“', '”', '}', ']', ')' };
string stringWithComment = "this has a “COMMENT” yeah really";
var result = stringWithComment.Split(delimiterComment);
//Output:
//result[0] = "this has a "
//result[1] = "COMMENT"
//result[2] = " yeah really"
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to cut off *comments*, e.g.

```
 123 (456 [789) abc ] -> 123 abc ]
```

In this case you can try a simple loop:

```
//TODO: I suggest combining starts and ends into array of pairs, e.g.
// KeyValuePair<string,string>[]
private static string CutOffComments(string source, char[] starts, char[] ends) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
    return source;

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(source.Length);

  int commentIndex = -1;

  foreach (var c in source) {
    if (commentIndex >= 0) { // within a comment, looking for its end
      if (c == ends[commentIndex])
        commentIndex = -1;
    }
    else { // out of comment, do we starting a new one?
      commentIndex = Array.IndexOf(starts, c);

      if (commentIndex < 0)
        sb.Append(c);
    }
  }

  //TODO:
  // if (commentIndex >= 0) // dungling comment, e.g. 123[456

  return sb.ToString(); 
}
```

Usage:

```
string source = "123[456]789";
// 123789
string result = CutOffComments(source, delimiterComment, delimiterEndComment);
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Just Put double quote between single quote without using escape character :**

```
private char[] delimiterComment = { '(', '{', '[', '\u201C', '"' };
private char[] delimiterEndComment = { ')', '}', ']', '\u201D', '"' };
```

**Input :**

```
string s = "abc(121), {12}, \" HI \"";
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,(s.Split(delimiterComment)).Select(s=> s)));
```

**Output :**

```
abc
121), 
12}, 
 HI
```

Comment: It is the curly quotes that dont work for me unfortunately